# How to convert next character pair to a hex integer

Tags: java

where I have to first reverse two bytes then convert that pair to hex integer. I am trying to convert it like below but it is giving error. Any idea to do that ? Thanks in advance

Here complete string : http://pastebin.com/1cSCyD78

Sample string

```
String str = "031890";
```

Error Message :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "0x30"
```

Java Code

```
for ( int start = 0; start < str.length(); start += 2 ) {
    try {
        String thisByte = new StringBuilder(str.substring(start, start+2)).reverse().toString();
        thisByte = "0x" + thisByte;
        int value = Integer.parseInt(thisByte, 16);
        char c = (char) value;
        System.out.println(c);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

### Update

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for ( int start = 0; start < str.length(); start += 2 ) {
    try {
        String thisByte = new StringBuilder(str.substring(start, start+2)).reverse().toString();
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(thisByte, 16));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Yes I Tried without prepending a "0x" to the string and now see my output looking weird.

[image]

Comment: Sorry,not understood what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks like you need 4 digits from your string per character, not 2.

Given that you interpret 2 digits as a character, though, at first glance, the output you showed in the picture does seem to match the string you posted on pastebin. You do get things that look like words in the output, so it's not totally off, and the gaps between the letters come from every second pair of 2 digits being '00'.

Not sure where this string came from, but if it was also generated by converting characters in some String to Bytes, it might make sense that it's 4 digits per character, since, for example, Java's `char`s are 16 bits (i.e. 2 bytes, i.e. 4 digits in your String) that encode the actual unicode symbol they represent in UTF-16.

If you are working off specs that someone else provided you with, maybe when they said "2 BYTES", they actually meant "two 8-bit numbers", which correspond to 4 digits (four 4-bit nibbles) in your hex string.

But your string looks like it contains binary data as well, not just characters. Do you know what are you actually expecting to see as the answer?

***Update (as per comment request)***:

It's a trivial change to your code, but here it is:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for ( int start = 0; start < str.length(); start += 4 ) {
    try {
        String thisByte = new StringBuilder(str.substring(start, start+4)).reverse().toString();
        output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(thisByte, 16));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

All I did was replace "2" with "4". :)

***Update (as per chat)***:

The code posted here to convert the hex-string into characters (using 4 digits per character) seems to work fine, but the hex-string does not seem to follow the convention the OP is expecting based on the specifications of the data, which caused part of the confusion.

***A side-note***:

If this is a public application, it is highly risky to include unencrypted SQL statements in the network traffic. If these statements are part of a request and get executed on the server, a hacker can use this to perform unwanted operations on the underlying data (e.g. stealing all phone numbers in the database). If it is merely some debug-/log-information sent to the client, it's still not a good idea as it may give hints to a hacker about the structure of your database and the way you access it, significantly simplifying a potential [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks, now it is looking like https://www.dropbox.com/s/js359m3k9pis5tx/screen1.png , yes this string has mobile number from byte byte[6] to byte[26], byte[27] to byte[47] but at that place it is weird characters there, can you please help me why it so ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to treat different sections in your String differently. Some correspond to text strings, which you can interpret with the code above, others might correspond to an integer value directly that should not be interpreted as characters (just grab the required number of digits and do `Integer.parseInt(...)`, but don't cast to `char`). Or it might be a different format entirely (some float encoding a date, who knows?). Without knowing the actual specifications of the data format you are trying to read, it'll be pretty impossible to help you out further.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by byte[6] to byte[26]? Those are part of the "lastautoin" piece of text (not weird characters). Would be quite the coincidence, also, if you'd decode a random phone number in a wrong way and end up with readable text... BTW: the weird characters are unicode symbols that you are seeing because the value at that point of the string did not correspond to a regular character.

Comment: Suppose there is "4700" and I need to Swap LSN:MSN characters to MSN:LSN for conversion so that should I take 0047 or 0074 ?

Comment: It depends entirely on the data format. Currently for text-decoding, you turn 4700 into 0074 and it seems to work. Having that many legible words come together by accident if you were doing something wrong is pretty much impossible. Whether that is also how you need to interpret the other binary data (phone numbers, whatever), I have no idea! Without the specs, it's not even clear whether the phone numbers are stored digit by digit or as one 64-bit long integer, or maybe even some floating point format, or as characters (although that choice seems to be out), or some other thing all together.

Comment: Do you have an example where you know what number you are expecting to get? That would help a lot. Are you even sure the numbers are there? Maybe it's just indices into some phone-book that's stored somewhere else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51924/discussion-between-williams-and-markus-a)

Answer (score 2):

Try without prepending a "0x" to the string. This prefix is only for the compiler. It's actually a shortcut for saying to use 16 as the radix.